# Fire trigger with cursor using Bulk Insert

Tags: c#, sql, triggers, cursor, bulkinsert

I am using BulkInsert - works fine - and trigger - works fine - with cursor which is not working I think. Would you please look at my code and tell me what is my mistake?

Thank you very much.

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CheckProducts] 
    ON  [dbo].[ProductsTemp]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @Manufacturer NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @Source NVARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE @SOurceDetailUrl NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @MainPrice DECIMAL;
        DECLARE @SalesPrice DECIMAL;
        DECLARE @Description NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @ImageUrl NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @GroupId INT;
        DECLARE @ParentCategoryId INT;
        DECLARE @CategoryId INT;

        DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
        SELECT Name, Manufacturer, Source, SourceDetailUrl, MainPrice, SalesPrice, [Description], ImageUrl, GroupId, ParentCategoryId, CategoryId
        FROM INSERTED

        OPEN curs
        FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @Name, @Manufacturer, @SourceDetailUrl, @MainPrice, @SalesPrice, @Description, @ImageUrl, @GroupId, @ParentCategoryId, @CategoryId
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN 
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Name = @Name AND Manufacturer = @Manufacturer AND Source = @Source AND SourceDetailUrl = @SourceDetailUrl)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Products SET MainPrice = @MainPrice, SalesPrice = @SalesPrice WHERE Name = @Name AND Manufacturer = @Manufacturer AND Source = @Source AND SourceDetailUrl = @SourceDetailUrl
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Products (Name, Manufacturer, MainPrice, SalesPrice, [Description], Source, SourceDetailUrl, ImageUrl, GroupId, ParentCategoryId, CategoryId)
                VALUES (@Name, @Manufacturer, @MainPrice, @SalesPrice, @Description, @Source, @SourceDetailUrl, @ImageUrl, @GroupId, @ParentCategoryId, @CategoryId)
            END

            DELETE FROM ProductsTemp WHERE Name = @Name AND Manufacturer = @Manufacturer AND Source = @Source AND SourceDetailUrl = @SourceDetailUrl
            FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @Name, @Manufacturer, @SourceDetailUrl, @MainPrice, @SalesPrice, @Description, @ImageUrl, @GroupId, @ParentCategoryId, @CategoryId
        END
        CLOSE curs
        DEALLOCATE curs
    END
```

Comment: Do you have any other triggers on ProductsTemp?

Comment: Nope. Just this one.

Comment: So you are deleting from productstemp the very values that you are inserting? Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @JasperSchellingerhout Once I've inserted data to temp table, I am checking that is that already in product table or not. So, if it exists, I am updating it otherwise inserting data. After this process is complete, I want to delete this data from temp table.